# search a analyzed field through the stored original value in elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

In elastic search I have a field that is analyzed and I am also storing the original value. I want to search the field with the stored value not the analyzed value.

Is there any way to do it?

note: I cannot make the field `not_analyzed`, because I am searching the analyzed values also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [multi fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3) type, which will allow to two store the field both `analyzed` for full text search and `not_analyzed` for exact matches.