# Elasticsearch - Query original field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating a typeahead search with ES. I want to have partial matches to I have an ngram analyzer. Additionally, I want things that match at the beginning of a field to come up higher, so I have a prefix_phrase query which is boosted.

My problem is that I need to query the original value in the prefix_phrase or it will match all of the matched ngrams, not giving me what I want.

Example:

```
emails: [test_123@gmail.com, 123_something@facebook.com]
search: 123
```

I want `123_something` to come back first. But because of the ngram analyzer the value `123@gmail.com` is also matching the prefix query.

Is there a way to query the original value of an analyzed field (aka the value that is actually stored in the document)

Something like this

```
{
   match: {
       query: 123
       type: 'prefix'
       fields: ["email"]
       original: 1
   }
}
```

Or do I need to just store the original value in a separate field?

This answer: [search a analyzed field through the stored original value in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156132/search-a-analyzed-field-through-the-stored-original-value-in-elasticsearch) points to documentation that doesn't exist. Looks like multifield values were deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach in this case is multi-fields, indeed, and the most recent documentation has been a bit restructured. You'll find out more about multi-fields [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields).

> It is often useful to index the same field in different ways for different purposes. For instance, a string field could be indexed as an analyzed field for full-text search, and as a not_analyzed field for sorting or aggregations. Alternatively, you could index a string field with the standard analyzer, the english analyzer, and the french analyzer.
>
> This is the purpose of multi-fields. Most datatypes support multi-fields via the fields parameter.

And a full example you can find [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/multi-fields.html).